# Get content from other database table based on an ID and rewrite URL

Tags: url-rewriting, database, page-template

I am currently using WordPress with SEO friendly permalinks.
One page of my website is a special one though, let's call it `http://example.org/locales`.
It is using a custom page template that loads values from a database table called "locales" and echoes the content to a html table.

*Database columns:*

**id**, **location**, **address**, **type**, **guid**

*Example content:*

**3, Yale, Burberry street 21, Apartment, 40VIEOUKK2VA07F2**

I have currently configured my PHP code in the custom page template so that the *location column* contains a link to the guid for each item like this:

```
echo "<td><a href=\"?guid=" . $row['guid'] . "\">" . $row['address'] . "</a></td>";
```

This gives me a link that looks like this:

```
http://example.org/locales/?guid=40VIEOUKK2VA07F2
```

Now I have two questions:

1. How do I proceed to actually load the details from a locale with a specific guid if they are stored in a different database table?
2. How do I make an URL rewrite for `/?guid=40VIEOUKK2VA07F2` so that it becomes something like `http://example.org/locales/burberry-street-21` 
   ?

Comment: Please consider splitting this into two specific questions, it is challenging to provide good answer to a two entirely different things at the same time. Also both querying database and rewrites are extensively covered around, some research effort might be in order. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Just because it is under wordpress doesn't make this special in any way, just use any php sample code that connects and retrieves data from a DB.
2. The way you describe things it is impossible. If the DB is outside of WordPress how can wordress know that `burberry-street-21` should be converted to `40VIEOUKK2VA07F2` before accessing the external DB?